# How to create new zones on a slave dns server automatically when new zones are added to the master dns server?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

For a long time I have used a single dns server. Now I want to create a secondary dns server to use as backup. I can create slave zones manually for all my domains and they get updated correctly. But it's unclear to me how to clone the whole dns server so that when a new zone is created on the primary server, the zone will be created accordingly on the slave one.

I can create a few scripts that periodically check on the master one for new zones and upload on the slave what is needed to create the slave zone. Is there any more clean method to do this?

I'm using two CentOS machine with BIND.

Comment: How do you create new primary zones?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to either use and configuration management software like Ansible, or scripts to run periodically, scanning the zones at the master and setting them up at the slave server.

In the first case, if you don't know Ansible or any other configuration management tool, you're gonna have to learn it first, but you'll use it to other projects. In the second, you're gonna create something that will be functional, but a little bit uglier, depending of your bash-scripting skills.

There are people who are already managing their BIND servers through Ansible, like [this](https://github.com/mcsrainbow/ansible-playbooks-bind9) and [this](https://github.com/resmo/ansible-role-bind) guy.